# Forwarding Emails from IMAP to Windows Exchange

Tags: email, exchange, windows-server-2012, imap

We're switching from a hosted mail received through IMAP to Windows Exchange Server 2013 but I'd want emails that arrive to the previous mail host to be available in exchange.

Is there any way such that Exchange is able to periodically check for new mail using IMAP and proceed to distribute them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange can't do that on it's own but there are 3rd party tools. Check out POPcon (http://www.servolutions.com/popcon.htm) - it's simple to set up and works with Exchange 2013.